# Stripe InvalidRequestException in java

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am trying to test Stripe payment API in my android app. The Android app sends a token (token is provided by Stripe to the Android app) to the server, and then the server uses the token charge the user via the Stripe charge API. Since I am testing the process, I am using the dummy values provided by Stripe, but when I initiate a charge call I get an `InvalidRequestException` on the server side. I am having hard time testing it. 
For clarity's sake, I am also adding an image.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
try {
    Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chargeParams.put("amount", jsonNode.get("amount")); // amount in cents, again
    chargeParams.put("currency", "USD");
    chargeParams.put("source", token);
    chargeParams.put("description", "charge from server");

    Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
    String des = charge.getDescription();
} 
catch (CardException e) {
    // The card has been declined
}
```

How can I test this process?
Please guide me into the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the screenshot, look at the detailed error message. It tells you what's wrong: your integration is sending the string `"<com.stripe.android.model.Token@..."` as the token to Stripe's API.

From your Android app, you're likely sending a string representation of the token to the server. Instead, you simply need to send the token ID. The token ID is a string that starts with `tok_` followed by random alphanumeric characters. You can access it by calling `getId()`.

Comment: Oh thank you. I guess they should mention it clearly in their documentation. This quote is from their documentation ```Your app will receive the token back, and can then send the token to an endpoint on your server, where it can be used to process a payment, establish recurring billing, or merely saved for later use.```

Comment: Can you please look into this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850331/what-is-connected-stripe-account-id-how-to-get-it-from-android-platform