# What is CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID? How to get it from android platform?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am working on Ride Sharing app and i choose `Stripe` as payment procedure. What happens in app that rider can tip to driver. For this i used this approach that, Rider will pay to the App's `stripe` account and then app will keep its percentage and then it will transfer remaining amount to driver's stripe account.

So far everything is going good.App has successfully charged the rider but bit confused about transfering amount to driver's stripe account. I have looked into stripe documentation which says i need driver's stripe account `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID`, which i am unable to find and unable to figure out what is it. What is stripe connect account is? how can i add user to stripe connect from android to my platform?

This is the code snippet provided by stripe

```
Stripe.apiKey = PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY;

Map<String, Object> transferParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
transferParams.put("amount", 1000);
transferParams.put("currency", "gbp");
transferParams.put("destination", {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID});

Transfer.create(transferParams);
```

It would be nice if someone explain this to me. Thanks P.s i don't want to use `webview` in my app in any case. I am not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three different ways to [create charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) with Connect :

- [direct charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) (i.e. with the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header)
- [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) (i.e. with the [`destination`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-destination) parameter)
- [separate charges and transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) (in which you first create a "normal" charge on your platform's account, then create transfers to send funds to the destination accounts)

Which way you should use depends on your exact use case, as it also determines who pays Stripe's fees and who's responsible for refunds and chargebacks. Check out [this paragraph](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#choosing-approach) to help you decide which way is best suited for your business.

In the first two cases, you'd specify your platform's cut with the [`application_fee`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-application_fee) parameter, and the destination account's ID (`"acct_..."`) in either the `Stripe-Account` header or the `destination` parameter.

The account ID should be in your database. If you use [standard accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts#standard-accounts) or [Express accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts), then you get it at the end of the [OAuth flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#token-request), in the `stripe_user_id` field. If you use [custom accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts#custom-accounts), then you get it in the [`id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object-id) field in the response to the [account creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account). In all cases, you need to save this ID in your database so you can retrieve it to issue API requests and accept payments on behalf of this account.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing this to me. But i am pretty much worried about ```OAuth flow``` I am using standalone account. Thing is i am using android platform and i don't want to use browser or webview for ```OAuth flow```  is there any other way??

Comment: If your user does not already have a Stripe account, you could use [deferred account activation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/deferred-accounts). You could do this from your backend, and let your user provide the required information directly from their dashboard, outside of your app. However, if your user does already have a Stripe account, then you have to implement the OAuth flow which requires using a browser / webview.

Comment: yes you were right about it. I needed to use webview for it. But you guys need to provide some sdk support of mobile version. That would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: I think this id has power for managing payments and needs to be stored as encrypted. If you store in a database, it will be saved in clear text and shown in database backups, logs etc.

Comment: Would you mind specifying how to access the stripe_user_id field, I went through the entire documentation but couldn't find a reference to it. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code, please improve this document.